# What is wrong with my json in context of jQuery.jsonParse?

Tags: php, json, parsing, exception

I'm getting an 'invalid json' exception for a set of json.  I tested the json in a validator.  I've placed the json inside of a php file and set the header to "contenttype:application/json; charset=utf-8."

Not sure what else could be the culprit.  I have my jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lehel/ZJPgt/1/)

Comment: That should be `content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8` with a dash between `content` and `type` and without a dot at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) doesnt load a URL, you pass it a json string. the function youre looking for is [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).